# Unable to run data driven Mstest from command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I am trying to run mstest from command line. When I run this with command line, I get the below error.

**Test has invalid DataSource attribute. Either DataSourceSettingName or ConnectionString and TableName must be specified and cannot be empty.**

**0/1 test(s) Passed, 1 Not Runnable**

This is a data driven test and the who test is run multiple times using the data in the spreadsheet.

Surprisingly, when I run it from Visual Studio IDE, I am able to run the test and able to get the results. Its only from command line I am facing this issue.

Below is how my test is looking

```
[TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("APITests")]
    [DataSource("System.Data.Odbc",
    "Dsn=Excel Files;" +
    "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" +
    "dbq=|DataDirectory|\\APITestData.xls;" +        
    "defaultdir=.;" +
    "driverid=790;" +
    "maxbuffersize=2048;" +
    "pagetimeout=5;" +
    "readonly=true",
    "APITestData$", 
    DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    [DeploymentItem("APITestData.xls")]
    public void PostAndValidateAPITests()
    {
        //UNIT TEST CASE CODE
    }
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated to run the test in command line.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add parameters to your test acccording to your datasource ?
I think there is 5 parameters in your test method descriptor :

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("APITests")]
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc",
"Dsn=Excel Files;" +
"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" +
"dbq=|DataDirectory|\\APITestData.xls;" +        
"defaultdir=.;" +
"driverid=790;" +
"maxbuffersize=2048;" +
"pagetimeout=5;" +
"readonly=true",
"APITestData$", 
DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[DeploymentItem("APITestData.xls")]
public void PostAndValidateAPITests(var Odbc, var param, var isReadonly, var API, var accessMethod)
{
    //UNIT TEST CASE CODE
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. I tried all options. FInally what worked was vstest.console.exe and got the result. Still not able to figure out why mstest.exe did not work.